# Moving camera to coordinates in an array

Tags: three.js

A set of cones serve as guides to the camera. 
The camera needs to move from one cone to another with pauses.

From what I've got so far, i get only one change in position.
What should be done to move the camera to all positions.

My hunch is that it is something to do with the loop, but not sure where i'm making the mistake.

Some fresh eyes would help. :)

here's the code

```
function cones(){
  //cone

  var left =  Math.PI / 2 ; // to set the orientation of the cones in the space
  var right = (-1 * Math.PI /2);
  var back = (1 * Math.PI);
  var front = (-1 * Math.PI);

// cone coordinates
  var spriteResponse = [];
   spriteResponse[0] = {ID:1, x: -106, y:50 ,z: 295, rotax:front, rotay:left };
   spriteResponse[1] = {ID:2, x: 156.5, y:47 ,z: 268, rotax:0, rotay:right};
   spriteResponse[2] = {ID:3, x: -67, y:53 ,z: 539, rotax:front, rotay:0 };
   spriteResponse[3] = {ID:4, x: -199, y:48 ,z: 423, rotax:0, rotay:left };


//creating the cones
   for(var i=0; i<spriteResponse.length;i++)
    {
    var cyl_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
    var cyl_width = 15;
    var cyl_height = 10;

    var cylGeometry = new THREE.ConeBufferGeometry(cyl_width, cyl_height, 32);
    // translate the cylinder geometry so that the desired point within the geometry is now at the origin

    cylGeometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 0, cyl_height/2, 0 ) );

    var cone = new THREE.Mesh(cylGeometry, cyl_material);

  cone.database_id = spriteResponse[i].ID;
  cone.position.set(spriteResponse[i].x,spriteResponse[i].y,spriteResponse[i].z );
  cone.rotation.x = 0.5*Math.PI;
  cone.rotation.y = spriteResponse[i].rotay;
    scene.add( cone );

  //  planes.push( cone );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(   55, // Angle
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, // Aspect Ratio.
      1, // Near view.
      5000 // Far view.
    );
  //
  for(var i=0; i<spriteResponse.length;i++)
   {
    var targetPosition = new THREE.Vector4(spriteResponse[i].x,spriteResponse[i].y,spriteResponse[i].z, 0.5*Math.PI, spriteResponse[i].rotay );
    var tween = new TWEEN.Tween( camera.position ).to( targetPosition, 5000 ); // duration 5s

    tween.start();

    setTimeout( () => {

      tween.stop(); // stop the tween after 1s
      console.log('stopped');
      targetPosition = new THREE.Vector4(spriteResponse[i].x,spriteResponse[i].y,spriteResponse[i].z, 0.5*Math.PI, spriteResponse[i].rotay );
     }, 1000 );

     setTimeout( () => {

      tween.start(); // restart it after 5s (it will last the entire duration)
      console.log('start');

    }, 5000 );
  }

  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/solved-tweening-the-rotation-of-a-camera/5656/9?u=prisoner849).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with the code:

The first major one is that you don't close the first loop when you should, which is before creating the camera. The second loop thus runs inside the first one, and since they use the *same* function-scoped counter variable, the outer loop will run only once.

The second major issue is that the timed-out callbacks (whatever their purpose is) refer to the *function-scoped* `i` variable, which will have changed to its final value before any of the callbacks are called. A solution for this kind of headache is to use block-scoped counters instead, defined by the `let` keyword.

The third major issue is that you don't use tween as intended. You pass a `THREE.Vector3` (`camera.position`) to it, but judging by [this tutorial](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/) you need to instead pass a literal object and use an event handler to update the `THREE.Vector3`.

The creation of a `THREE.Vector4` from 5 arguments makes little sense.

X rotations are defined in `spriteResponse`, but a common constant is applied instead during object creation.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to give an assessment of this code. Really appreciate your pointing out the problems as most would have escaped me. I am still learning three.js. I will review what I've got after considering all the feedback received.

Answer (score 0):

Approached the problem a different way - solved it using camera.position tween chains with delays for the pauses.

Thank you prisoner849 and Elias Hasle for your comments and suggestions!
Appreciate the patient people in this forum who help out newbies like me :)